# How to call urls.py fetching a value from a loop in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

On my index page, I have an image gallery. When someone clicks on an image,  it should show more information with more photos in another page. All are loading from MySQL database using a `for` loop. I'm unable to get the detail of clicked image from my data base. It loads all the data

This page's process is like a news website -- all the news loading from a loop. if someone clicks on a news item it should only show details about the clicked item.

Below is my `index.html` page, my `urls.py` and `views.py` source code also.

I'm using Python, Django with MySQL; all latest versions.

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZaDl.jpg), [source code of my images gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTx0d.jpg)

```
{% for x in destination %}
<!-- Destination -->
<a href="destination" id="{{x.id}}"><div class="destination item" >
    <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="{{x.img.url}}" alt="">
        {% if x.offer %}
        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a >Special Offer</a></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="">{{x.name}}</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{x.short_description}}</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From ${{x.price}}</div>
    </div>
</div></a>

{% endfor %}
```

```python
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('destination', views.destination, name='destination'),
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination


def destination(request):
    dest = Destination
    return render(request, 'destination.html', {'sub_destination': dest})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). just add another url pattern in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('destination/<int:dest>/', views.destination_content, name='destination_content'),
    # ...
]
```

and use it inside your for loop in template like this:

```
    <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="{% url 'destination_content' x.id %}">{{x.name}}</a></div>
        ...
    </div>
```

**NOTE**: you must define `destination_content` function in your `views.py`

Comment: @user3484272 if it solved you problem accept the answer for future readers

Comment: Thank you so much. unfortunately it's not working still how I'm expecting because of my limited knowledge. however you change my mind, in a good way to follow-up with those guides. l have never learn about reverse URL "Reverse resolution of URLs" l am deeply following them up. thank you so much kindly explanin me with examples. I wish you good luck . if you are using any social media let me know .